# no puedo registrar un usuario en laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc

Archivo del controlador de registro estoy intentando registrar un usuario a una tabla llamada usuarios no me arroja ningún error a la hora de guardar solo nos los guarda

```
use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nombre' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'apellido' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'pass' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'pass' => bcrypt($data['pass']),
        'tipo_user' => $data['tipo_user'],
    ]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamas al modelo `User` Laravel utiliza la tabla de tu base de datos llamada `users` si quieres cambiarlo debes entrar a tu modelo `User` y agregar lo siguiente `protected $table = 'usuarios';`, también recuerda tener tus atributos `fillable` ejemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Si ese no es el problema, intenta crear otra tabla y agregarle datos sin validaciones para probar que la conexión esta bien.

Tambien puedes probar usado el Query Builder, ejemplo:

```
DB::table('usuarios')->insert(
    [
        'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'pass' => bcrypt($data['pass']),
        'tipo_user' => $data['tipo_user'],
    ]
);
```

Comment: amigo tendrá algo que ver el cache o algo así coloque el query builder ya había agregado la tabla al modelo y igual sigue sin mostrar ningún error solo no guarda y me devuelve a la pagina

Comment: este es mi archivo de modelo user 
  
     protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'password', 'tipo_user','remember_token',
    ];

Comment: y la conexión esta bien ya que el me consulta unos datos que ya tengo pre cargados pero no me quiere guardar el usuario y lo pero es que no arroja ningún error

Answer (score 0):

Hola al final lo pude lograr pero me toco mantener los campos de la tabla y de el controlador totalmente iguales ya que si los cambio no me funciona ejemplo en la tabla en vez de nombre me toco dejarlo name y en el validador y en el

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'pass' => bcrypt($data['pass']),
        'tipo_user' => $data['tipo_user'],
    ]);
}
}
```

me toco dejarlo así y en la tabla tenia id_user y no lo tomaba me toco dejarlo como id si alguno tiene una forma de arreglar esto se lo agradecería ya que realmente no conseguí como y también tuve que agregar la linea al modelo  protected $table = 'usuarios'; la cual la menciono @Fer